# Does any one Know of any Tools to monitor GC on a transaction application on IBM's J9 VM?

Tags: garbage-collection, j9

I have been tasked to tune the GC on an application, and I am looking for a tool that will help me monitor the GC in depth, what collection is happening, how often, how it is affecting run time. Any one know of any good tools fo J9 VM?

Answer (score 0):

To monitor GC activity in the IBM runtime for Java, use Health Center or enable the verbose gc log and analyze it with GCMV.

Health Center is a tool that can do live monitoring of the JVM including gc activity, threads, configuration, profiling and so on. Alternatively you can write Health Center data to a file and analyze it later.

To get even more detail that Health Center provides, you can turn on verbose GC logging with -Xverbose:gc, then a log of all gc activity is printed to stderr. You can write it to a log file with -Xverbosegclog:.

To analyze and graph the information in the verbose gc log, you can use the GCMV (Garbage Collection and Memory Visualizer) tool.

Health Center and GCMV are both available from:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools